# Append new objects to existing Constraint layout of an activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have been trying to insert current time on new textview below of an existing textview (Note switch is at the top of activity)whenever Switch is On ,relavant object description of the activity are as follows:
Activity id:stpclk

Existing textview id:lstview

The following code stopped the app in emulator,I have tried changing
final ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.stpclk);
with

```
final ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = new ConstraintLayout(this);
```

following change works but my previos layout(switch and previous textview)
does not retain,My objective is to retain time along with existing layout objects

Can somebody help me I am new to android programming?

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Switch mySwitch=(Switch)findViewById(R.id.toggleid);
    final TextView txtview2= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lstview);
    final Switch mySwitch=(Switch)findViewById(R.id.toggleid);
    final ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.stpclk);

            mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    // do something, the isChecked will be
                    if(mySwitch.isChecked()){
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                        curr_time[0] = sdf.format(new Date());

                    }
                    else{
                        TextView ctime = new TextView(StopClock.this);
                        ctime.setText(curr_time[0]);
                        ctime.setTextSize(25);
                        ctime.setId(View.generateViewId());

                        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams clpcontactUs = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        ctime.setLayoutParams(clpcontactUs);

                        constraintLayout.addView(ctime);

                        ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
                        constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);
                        constraintSet.connect(ctime.getId(),ConstraintSet.TOP,txtview2.getId(),ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,18);
                        constraintSet.connect(ctime.getId(),ConstraintSet.LEFT,txtview2.getId(),ConstraintSet.LEFT,18);
                        constraintSet.connect(ctime.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, txtview2.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 18);

                        constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
                        constraintLayout.setId(R.id.stopclkid);
                        setContentView(constraintLayout);

                    }
                    // true if the switch is in the On position
                }

            });
    }
```